# Não aparece o assistente de criação de banco no service based database e não cria uma connection string no app.config no entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, webforms, visual-studio-2015, app.config

Estou fazendo um curso virtual de entity framework na qual o instrutor utiliza o visual studio na versão 2012 e durante a aula ele cria um projeto web form e pede para criar um banco de dados no template service-based-database ao criar um novo item, e logo depois ao criar o template aparece o menu de assistente de criação de bancos na qual aparece duas opções para escolher- o 'dataset' e o 'entity data model', o instrutor escolhe o dataset e depois de criar o arquivo mdf ele diz que automaticamente no arquivo app.config é criado uma tag 'connectionstrings'. O meu problema é que o meu visual studio é na versão 2015 e ao eu clicar no service-based-database ele cria o arquivo de banco mdf automaticamente sem aparecer o menu de assistente de criação com as duas opções dataset e entity data model, e também nao cria as connections strings no app.config. Gostaria de saber como se faz para aparecer o menu com as duas opções no service based database e criar uma connectionstring automaticamente.